# Appium server is not starting from java program

Tags: java, appium

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Could not
> ```
>
> start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote
>   server or browser start-up failure. Build info: version: '2.52.0',
>   revision: '4c2593cfc3689a7fcd7be52549167e5ccc93ad28', time:
>   '2016-02-11 11:22:43' System info: host: 'BLR-L1516-01157', ip:
>   '10.246.20.28', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_73' Driver info: driver.version:
>   AndroidDriver     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:180)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:249)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:158)
>     at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:109)
>     at
>   io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:39)
>     at Driver_class.linear_ebayapp.main(linear_ebayapp.java:47) Caused
>   by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to
>   127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:140)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:314)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:363)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:219)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:195)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:86)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:186)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:57)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.fallBackExecute(ApacheHttpClient.java:144)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:90)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
>     ... 7 more Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused:
>   connect   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native
>   Method)   at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:72)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.conn.HttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(HttpClientConnectionOperator.java:117)
>     ... 20 more